Finding the Lie algebra of a matrix group
If the (connected) Lie group $G$ is defined as follows:
$$G = \left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}: a\in \mathbb{R}^+, b\in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$
I am not sure how to find the Lie algebra corresponding to this Lie group. I know that it is the tangent space at the identity, but how do I compute this? For $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$, I used the fact that the determinant of a matrix in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $1$ and then differentiate the entries with respect to $t$ to get conditions on the entries of any matrix in $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$, but I don't think I can use the same trick here. Any help is appreciated!

See also this duplicate, for the Lie algebra of th affine group.

Consider a smooth curve of matrices
$\gamma(t)=
\begin{pmatrix}
a(t)&b(t)\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}$
with $a$ strictly positive and $b$ real-valued and such that $\gamma(0)=I$. Then, the velocity vector $\gamma’(0)$ is? Therefore?

$\gamma'(t) = \begin{pmatrix} a'(t) & b'(t) \ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, so $a'(0)\in \mathbb{R}$ and $b'(0)=0$? Are these the only conditions?

@user13121312 where did you get the second condition from?

I thought $b(0)=0 \implies b'(0)=0$ but this is false, so $b'(0)\in \mathbb{R}$ as well. So the tangent space is all matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} x & y \ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$?

@user13121312 yup.
